# Sort on  multiple NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a 2 dimensional numpy array that contains stock returns.  I want to sum the return every 2 days, and if the sum is in the top two, I will set every element in a similar shaped array to True.

For example, returns below is the daily returns for four different stocks.

`returns=np.array([

       [0, 0, 4, 8],

       [7, 5, 4, 1],

       [10, 5, 7, 6],

       [7, 5, 4, 2]])`

For the first two days, columns 2 and 3 (using 0 based indexing) have the highest sums. For the second set of two days, columns 0 and 2 have the highest sums. The output array I want is

`bools=np.array([

       [False, False, True, True],

       [False, False, True, True],

       [True, False, True, False],

       [True, False, True, False]])`

What are good ways to accomplish this?

If there are ties with the sums of two days, I want to use another similarly shaped numpy array as tiebreakers.

For example, if

`returns=np.array([

       [0, 9, 4, 8],

       [7, 5, 4, 0],

       [10, 5, 7, 6],

       [7, 5, 4, 2]])`

For the first set of two days, columns 2 and 3 are tied for the second highest sum. I want to decide the tiebreaker by the greatest value in the last row for the tied columns so that the tie break between columns 2 and 3 look at tiebreaks[1][2] vs tiebreaks[1][3] (4 v 5), and that the ultimate output is bools2.

`tiebreaks=np.array([

       [0, 0, 1, 1],

       [2, 3, 4, 5],

       [0, 5, 7, 6],

       [-7, 5, -4, 2]])`

`bools2=np.array([

       [False, True, False, True],

       [False, True, False, True],

       [True, False, True, False],

       [True, False, True, False]])`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your example, things appear already sorted according to your criteria and the `names` array has an apparent unnecessary dimension.  It would be helpful if you could provide a more realistic example and an example of the desired outcome.

Comment: Your edit has made this a completely different question.  Please roll back the edit and ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.lexsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to get the indices that sort your arrays using `prices` as primary key and `names` as secondary key.  Applying advanced indexing using these indices yields the sorted arrays:

```
col_indices = numpy.lexsort((names, prices))
row_indices = numpy.arange(len(names))[:, None]
print(prices[row_indices, col_indices])
print(names[row_indices, col_indices])
```

(Note that in your example, `names` and `prices` don't have compatible shapes.)